# What exactly does the relation over the set $X$ mean concerning orbits?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

My book says this:

> Suppose that $G$ is a group of permutations of a set $X$. We shall show that the group structure of $G$ leads naturally to a partition of $X$.
>
> Define a relation $\sim$ on $X$ by the rule
>
> $$ x \sim y \iff g(x) = y \text{ for some } g \in G $$

Lets say that $X$ is the set $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$, then a group of permutations of $X$ could be $\{ (1)(2)(3), (123), (132) \} = H$.

As I've understood it, group elements act on group elements. For example, $(123) \cdot (132) = (1)(2)(3) \in H$.

But what does $g(x) \mid g ∈ G$ mean? I assume $x, y \in X$ which would be either $1$, $2$ or $3$ in the example, but $g$ doesn't have the binary operation defined over elements of $X$?

I'm sorry if this is very basic :(

Comment: When you write down a permutation in terms of cycles as in $(123)$, it's shorthand for the function from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to $\{1, 2, 3\}$ which sends $1 \mapsto 2$, $2 \mapsto 3$, $3 \mapsto 1$. So in this example there is just one orbit: all of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, I assume, you have come across the group actions. I shall write about the notion of orbits here, along the same lines of your definition:

> Firstly, let me clarify, that, $g(x)|g \in G,x \in X$ stands for the following: Since $G$ is a group of permutations, we interpret the elements of $G$ as bijections of $G$ onto $G$. This in particular means $g$ is a function and takes values in $X$. So, $g(x)$ is another element in $X$.
>
> For instance, if, $g=(123)$, then, $g(1)=2;~g(2)=3;~g(3)=1$.

Now let's talk about these orbits!

Define a relation $\sim$ on $X$, $x \sim y \iff \exists~~g \in G ~~~\text{s.t}~~ g(x)=y$.

Now I claim that this is an equivalence relation:

- It is **reflexive.** Since, $G$ is a group, the identity element exists in $G$ and takes any element to itself.
- It is **transitive**. Suppose $g(x)=y$ and $h(y)=z$, then $h \circ g(x)=y$ and note that $h \circ g$ is a well-defined member of $G$.
- It is **Symmetric**. Suppose $g(x)=y$. Then, $g^{-1}(y)=x$, and yet again, thanks to the group structure on $G$. We have that, inverses exist for elements in $G$ (and, infact they are unique!)

Now, an equivalence relation partitions the set into disjoint sets, called equivalence classes. (Prove this, if you are not aware of it!)

So, *"your claim that group structure on $G$ partitions $X$ quite naturally"* is justified!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Wish I could +1 you again, but atleast thanks again (for the update)